# Find all the IP address of DELETE after two consecutive GET requests

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file `Find all the IP address of DELETE after two consecutive GET requests.`

```
192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.0" "/Safari/5322"
10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.0" "/Safari/5322"
98.5.45.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] "DELETE  Firefox/3.8"
94.5.6.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:48:56 +0000] "DELETE  Firefox/3.8"
192.168.1.2 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.0" "/Safari/5322"
10.30.24.12 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.0" "/Safari/5322"
98.5.45.34 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] "DELETE  Firefox/3.8"
```

Expected Out
`['98.5.45.3','94.5.6.3','98.5.45.34']`

My Code

```
import re
s =  open(r'C:/Users/apache_log.log').read()
expr = r'GET.*?GET[^\n]*\n(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
print(re.findall(expr, s, re.DOTALL))
```

above expression will give IP address from 2 GET request

Comment: Must regex be the only solution?  If there are requirements that the IP address of the client must make the `GET` before the `DELETE`, it would be much easier to track them individually by a mapping, while iterating through the log file line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex here with some tempered dot logic:

```
log = """192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] \"GET HTTP/1.0\" \"/Safari/5322\"
10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] \"GET HTTP/1.0\" \"/Safari/5322\"
98.5.45.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] \"DELETE  Firefox/3.8\"
94.5.6.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:48:56 +0000] \"DELETE  Firefox/3.8\"
192.168.1.2 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] \"GET HTTP/1.0\" \"/Safari/5322\"
10.30.24.12 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] \"GET HTTP/1.0\" \"/Safari/5322\"
98.5.45.34 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] \"DELETE  Firefox/3.8\""""

matches = re.findall(r'GET(?:(?!(?:POST|PUT|GET|DELETE)).)*(?:(?!(?:POST|PUT|GET|DELETE)).)*\n(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?:(?!(?:POST|PUT|GET|DELETE)).)*\"DELETE', log, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['98.5.45.3', '98.5.45.34']
```

However, I would probably just write a simple parser which reads line by line to find the IP matches.

Comment: i think you missed 94.5.6.3

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen funny because he wrote the question :)(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you explain the regex, also why dotall required here. +1 for strange regex :)